# Print a part of web page in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, css, printing

I have created a Booking Web Application. Post data entry a receipt is generated on a table in HTML with values populated from the database. I would like to print the receipt on a paper which is 4 inch Breadth and 5.5 inch in Length. On the paper 1 inch from top contains company name and address. I have created the receipt table in HTML in a way to leave 1 inch space from the top. I guess I would need to do a postback if using C#. Also on a successful print, the record needs to be marked as Printed (I can take of the coding part). Please advice where to insert the code for marking the successful print.

[image: Receipt]

Please help in a easy way to print the receipt. Thanks

How can I print using CSS or Javascript?

Comment: This question is so unclear that it is likely to get closed unless you work on clarification. A little code might help, too.

Comment: Well I just need some directions and code to print using C#. I would like to print the data that you see in the image. The data is present in a <table> place in a form on an ASPX page.

Comment: Printing things from a browser is beyond c# which only works on the server. You need to work with browser technologies like Javascript, jQuery and CSS for formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
@media print
{
#non-printable { display: none; }
#printable {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="printable" >
Your content to print
</div>
<div id='non-printable'>
this is not printable section
</div>
<input type="button" id="non-printable" class=normaltext onclick="JavaScript:window.print();" value="print" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Their is no way to capture the client side screen to server. if their is a API exist then their is a no guarantee then this work with old browser.

simply use print css. someone have answered it already. same trick work fine even in old IE.